# How to generate random numbers to make fixed result?

Tags: javascript, random

I have this formula:

(x + y + z + t)/4.8 = 3.7

I want to be able to generate random numbers (integer) from 1 to 8 for all variables in order to get to that 3.7 final result.

I tried nested loop but somehow it didn't work :( I'm learning Javascript.

I appreciate every help.

Comment: how random do you want to be, because if you use as many digits as `Math.random` offers, your program won't finish any time soon?

Comment: Hi good question. I should've put that in my OP. yeah I want the numbers to be integer, so it would narrow down pretty much.

Comment: Why random? Given the short range of each variable, you could probably do this iteratively (3 nested loops) faster than choosing random numbers

Comment: This doesn't seem particularly difficult, especially if you use nested loops. Kinda seems you just want someone to do your homework.

Comment: This will still never ever terminate.

Comment: it is difficult in that I'm a newbie and have spent the whole morning to figure it out but couldn't. I will learn from whatever suggestion/help you give me, not just to have something to copy and paste.

Comment: Hi Phil, how could 3 nested loops solve this? My initial thought is the first loop would be to loop from 1 to 6 for x, second loop is 1 to 6 for y, and the third loop is from 1 to 8 for ( z and that x + y = (3.2*4.8)-z). Is that what you have in mind? I tried this but somehow it didn't work :(

Comment: _"how could 3 nested loops solve this?"_ Well, it can't actually but that's because your conditions are unsatisfiable. Essentially though, you can try all combinations iteratively... _for (x in 1..6) for (y in 1..6) for (z in 1..8) { ... }_

Comment: its even more impossible if you add the requirement result by 0.5

Comment: Think about your changes logically. You're now asking for four **integers** that when summed equal **17.76**

Comment: @Phil: you're correct. I should've thought about it logically before jumping into it. I'll close the topic and ask more rational questions only after thinking it through first.

Comment: x + y + z + t=17.76. Summing four integer randoms to have fixed integer sum is trivial. Summing four integer randoms to have fixed floating point sum is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all, set a variable with value of 3.2 * 4.8, this is `x + y + z - 7`

```
target = 3.2 * 4.8
```

next add target with 7, so we get `x + y + z` this gets us `22.36`

then get z and x

```
z = Math.random() * 8;
x = Math.random() * 6;
```

lets say we get max number for both, that is z = 8, and x = 6

then get y

```
y = target - x - z
```

so `y = 22.36 - 8 - 6` that is `8.36` which is larger than 6 (out of range), therefore its an impossible requirement

```js
target = 3.2 * 4.8 + 7;
z = 8;
x = 6;
y = target - x - z;
console.log(x, y, z, target);
```

Comment: nice one @Phil :D

Comment: Hi. I understand it now. I just fixed the conditions and I think I could finally figure out with nested loops. I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @TrungHà nope, it's still impossible

Answer (score 0):

First, get all the value of x, y, z that satisfy the equation. Then pick random result from **satisfyResults**.
There is no match for you case here for every integer value of x, y, z in your pre-define range.

```js
var satisfyResults = [];
for(var x=1;x<=6; x++) { 
    for(var y=1;y<=6;y++) { 
        for(var z=1;z<=8;z++) { 
            if ((x + y + (z-7)) / 4.8 === 3.2) { 
                satisfyResults.push([x, y, z])
            }
        }
    } 
}

if (satisfyResults.length <= 0) {
  console.log("There is no match!")
} else {
  var result = satisfyResults[Math.floor(Math.random() * satisfyResults.length)]
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution as loop will go on till value not equal to `3.7`.

```js
function getRand(min,max){ return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min) } 

var result;

while (result !== 3.7) {
  x = getRand(1,8);
  y = getRand(1,8);
  z = getRand(1,8);
  t = getRand(1,8);
  console.log('x : ', x ,' y : ', y ,'z : ', z ,'t :', t);
 result = Math.round( ((x + y + z + t)/4.8 ) * 10 ) / 10;
  console.log('result : ', result);
}
```